# Cast object returned from library function as inherited type in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

The library I'm using has a function that returns an object of type A.

```
a = the_lib.lib_function()  # returns an object of type A
```

I have a class, B, that inherits from A.

```
class B(A):
    def my_method(self):
        print "This is Travis's class"
```

I want the constructor of B to call the library function and wrap the A object that is returned. I saw the answer to a different question that did this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        a = the_lib.lib_function()
        self.__dict__ = a.__dict__

    def my_method(self):
        print "This is Travis's class"
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does the assignment of `__dict__` work? If it does, what would make a different way of doing this "better"? (That said, your approach won't work for classes that use `__slots__`.)

Comment: Good point on `__slots__`, but that would seem to me to be more of an edge case in general.

Comment: Also: why use inheritance *at all*? Seems like `my_method` could just be a function that takes a parameter of type `A`. Generally speaking, why do you **need** to do this sort of magic?

Comment: It's not just `__slots__`; it's anything other than normal `__dict__` attributes—e.g., dynamic `__getattr__` attributes. If that's not a problem, that's fine, but you have to make sure it's not a problem.

Comment: @millimoose When I tried it out, the assignment of __dict__ didn't seem to work. In this case, my_method could be a function but in the actual class I'm using, it's a method that modifies the state of the object.

Comment: Adding to millimoose's point: If you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish here, instead of how you want to accomplish it, we can probably give you a better way to do it. In other words, this smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @travis1097: A function can modify the state of the object in exactly the same way a method can. There are no "private attributes" in Python.

Comment: @millimoose Therefore, I really do need the caller to be able to call methods defined A or B.

Comment: Okay, but why does `B` and `A` have to be the *same* object. Can't `B` just have an attribute `a` that the caller would access explicitly? Generally, having one object "become" (but not quite completely) another object is just really, really fiddly, compared to having the calling code deal with two objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would just forwarding all attribute accesses that `B` doesn't provide to `A` work for your purposes? I.e. like this:

```
class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__a = the_lib.lib_function()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__a, name)

    # maybe define __setattr__ too, and other __magic__ methods

    def my_method(self):
        # ...
```

That said, this has a few caveats. For one, `B` can't inherit from `A`, which would foil instanceof checks. Also, most `__magic__` methods will require wrapping manually as well.

Comment: While I think the proxy approach may be acceptable in some cases, I personally like the `self.__dict__ = other.__dict__` approach better in general.

Comment: If necessary, you can fake `isinstance` too—e.g., by using ABCs. The fact that you have to explicitly implement dunder methods instead of relying on `__getattr__` is a bit of a downside—but you can work around that by just copying all of A's methods to B right after defining B.

Comment: @sberry Honestly, having thought about this more after the answer, my preferred approach would be "not doing this sort of thing at all". It's also hard to provide a "better" way of doing X when the question doesn't say better how.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding functionality by attempting to inherit from `A`, just [monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982/505154) the instance of `A` returned by `the_lib.lib_function()`.  For example:

```
import types

def my_method(self):
    print "This is Travis's class"

def B():
    a = the_lib.lib_function()
    a.my_method = types.MethodType(my_method, a)
    return a
```

This will give you a function that you can use like a class to return instances of `A` as returned by `the_lib.lib_function()`, but those instances will also include `my_method`.

Comment: An alternate using `new`, `a.my_method = new.instancemethod(my_method, a, a.__class__)`

Comment: ...however `new` is deprecated.

Comment: … and it does exactly the same thing as `types.MethodType`, just less readably, so it's not a very useful alternative unless you really need to support Python 2.1 or something…

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives to what you're trying to do.

---

If you just need `my_method` to access attributes of the `A` instance, you don't need to do anything. Python has no "private attributes"; there is no difference between accessing an attribute via the `self` argument vs. accessing it via any other argument. So:

```
def my_method(a):
    a.state.count += 1
    print "This is Travis's class"
a = the_lib.lib_function()
my_method(a)
```

---

If you really want to attach the method to `a` as a bound method, you can do that without having to monkey about with classes:

```
a = the_lib.lib_function()
a.my_method = types.MethodType(my_method, a, type(a))
```

---

If you really do need to wrap the A instance, it's often better to do it by delegation than by inheritance. Whether you do this by statically delegating the methods you need, dynamically building the delegation methods right after the class definition, dynamically building them at construction time, or just using `__getattr__` to do it on the fly depends on your actual needs.

---

If you want B to act as a subclass of A even though it isn't one, you can use [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) to fool `isinstance`, etc.

---

Or you can even turn the B instance into an A instance (e.g., by changing its `__class__`)—but keep in mind that this will make it use A's implementations of most dunder methods (including `__getattr__`).

---

If you really want B to be a subclass, you can write an `__init__` constructor (or a classmethod alternate constructor) that copies over the attributes. Again, you can do this with a static set of attributes, or dynamically (just remember that `__dict__` doesn't handle `__slots__`, dynamic `__getattr__` attributes, `@property` and similar fake attributes, some attributes inherited from builtin/extension classes, etc.).

---

So, which one is right?

Without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish, it's impossible to answer that. All of these are right in some cases, although some of them are right far more rarely than others.